# Fail to convert to internal representation Spring data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data and trying to fetch an entity but it is failing to load its child element,Please see below code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Pub")
public class Pub {

    private Integer id;
    private Date plannedDate;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    private Sub sub;

    private Date creationDate;
    private Date updateDate;

    private String log;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen", sequenceName = "sq_gen", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 19)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "PLANNED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getPlannedDate() {
        return plannedDate;
    }
    public void setPlannedDate(Date plannedDate) {
        this.plannedDate = plannedDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUB_ID")
    public Sub getSub() {
        return sub;
    }
    public void setSub(Sub sub) {
        this.sub = sub;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE" , nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }
    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }
    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "LOG", nullable = false)
    public String getLog() {
        return log;
    }
    public void setLog(String log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

     public String toString() {
            return "" + id + " - " + status + " - " + subscription;
        }

}
```

In repository

```
@Query("select p from Pub p where p.id=:pubId")
    public Publication getByPubIdId(@Param("pubId") Integer pubId);
```

Exception i am getting is , failing while retrieving Sub(child entity) . I have unidirectional relationship from Pub to Sub (Many to One) , does this can cause below error? please suggest

```
2016-09-21 13:47:32.912  WARN 1764 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17059, SQLState: 99999
2016-09-21 13:47:32.912 ERROR 1764 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Fail to convert to internal representation
2016-09-21 13:47:32.912  INFO 1764 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.entity.Sub#1283]
2016-09-21 13:47:33.240 ERROR 1764 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[servletContainer]     : Servlet.service() for servlet [servletContainer] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.Sub#1283]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.entity.Sub#1283]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getInt(CharCommonAccessor.java:147) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor.getInt(T4CVarcharAccessor.java:818) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:928) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:434) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have checked , names of columns are same as defined in entity.Am i missing on something? I am using Spring data first time.

Comment: Please add you Sub Entity code and Table definitions.

Comment: Also your `Publication` class, or is that a typo? Do the normal `CrudRepository` methods work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it. In my sub entity I was having enum , after extracting it in other class I am able to fetch records. Previously my sub entity was

```
private SubType isMailOrFtp;
enum SubType {
  SUB_MAIL, SUB_FTP   
}
```

I removed enum from it.

Thanks a lot